# Предсказание цены в зависимости от времени

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Всем привет, какую модель нужно применять , когда нужно предсказать прибыль в зависимости от года и номера недели. То есть есть данные за 2019 и 2020 год, нужно предсказать на 2021? Подойдет ли здесь линейная регрессия?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20polynomial%20regression%20is,nth%20degree%20polynomial%20in%20x.

Comment: Ну, в первом приближении - можно попробовать линейную регрессию. Но вообще не всё так просто обычно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если вы задали вопрос с тегом "машинное обучение", то ответ лежит в анализе временных рядов. Правда, по двум годам строить модель на год вперед -  задание еще то, и точность будет очень грубой, но стандартные шаги понятны.

Если ваш товар имеет склонность к сезонности - не важно недельной, месячной и годовой -  то это надо подтвердить (например, используя анализ автокорреляций) и обнаружить период (или периоды - так бывает) сезонности и выделить сезонную составляющую из общей модели ряда.  Потом - или перед -  по разному делают - надо выделить трендовую составляющую. Тут неизвестно, какой именно метод сработает - скользящего среднего, регрессии (линейной -  но вовсе не обязательно), взвешенного среднего - надо пробовать и считать точность. После этого у вас в руках останется "шум" - его надо бы по хорошему проверить на "нормальность" распределения. И вот имея эти три компоненты - можно строить свои предсказания.

Если же ряд окажется не сезонный, то тут могут оказаться полезными модели -  либо Брауна, Хольта-Винтерса, либо ARIMA. Они позволяют строить модели поведения ряда и предсказывать вперед на несколько шагов.

Если уж совсем хочется поразвлекаться - то LSTM-нейросети.

Программная реализация всех этих методов есть в Scikit-Learn, кое что - Scipy. Из более тяжелой артиллерии - TF, PyTorch  или как уже подсказал уважаемый CrazyElf - Prophet.

Answer (score 2):

`Time Series` - довольно непростая область машинного обучения. В первом приближении вполне можно попробовать линейную регрессию.

Но обычно линейной регрессии мало - нужно выделять тренды, сезонность и прочие факторы и корректно с ними работать. Хорошая новость состоит в том, что есть современные мощные библиотеки для этого, например [Facebook Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/).